# Floating a Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to float a div with text content in it to the left of a Bootstrap Carousel, but the results make no sense. Can someone help me out?
It seems like the elements are staying block, even though I specify them as inline. Could this have to do with Bootstrap itself?

I've also included the CSS just in case it helps.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div id="elSlideShow">
        <div id="slideShowLeft">
            <h2>Description of Piano</h2>
            <p>werg wer foierjfoi  jerij eri ioerjioj eruueruer uerueuerguerurhgueruig eurgu eruig eruiguerguer ueruigerigneign</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slideShowRight">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#666:#444/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#555:#333/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>


h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
#slideShowLeft {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 40%;
}
#slideShowRight {
    width: 55%;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply float them by using "float: left;" property. Put it in either CSS or in div, like style="float:left;"

https://fiddle.jshell.net/odzbg8rh/
You can adjust the distance between each button in CSS

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code and its working. Just a few points to correct.

1. Remove `display: inline` from your css as you are using `float` and when applied `float` to elements, it makes them `block`. So `display: inline` makes no sense when using with `float`.
2. Add class `clearfix` to parent of floating elements to set their layout.
   `<div id="elSlideShow" class="clearfix">`

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#slideShowLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
#slideShowRight {
  width: 55%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container"> 
  <div id="elSlideShow" class="clearfix">
    <div id="slideShowLeft">
      <h2>Description of Piano</h2>
      <p>werg wer foierjfoi  jerij eri ioerjioj eruueruer uerueuerguerurhgueruig eurgu eruig eruiguerguer ueruigerigneign</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slideShowRight">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#666:#444/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img data-src="holder.js/1140x500/auto/#555:#333/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help people, actually the problem was a list that came before. The fact that I floated that list probably messed with these elements. My solution was to add a line break after that list.